# Unwind 2 arrays separately without using $facet in mongodb 3.2x

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

**Objective:** I need to pull out posts and shares and sort then according to date and time and put them together into a single array of Objects

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5919e1f8b1f75c2b1cb504ea"
    },
    "user": {
        "$oid": "58deb7db5aac7a0011d7bdf4"
    },
    "likes": [],
    "comments": [],
    "posts": [
        {
            "p_Id": {
                "$oid": "596b16b1c657d21d8048287d"
            },
            "Date": {
                "$date": "2017-07-16T07:33:06.238Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "p_Id": {
                "$oid": "596b3068183c4f24d853f228"
            },
            "Date": {
                "$date": "2017-07-16T09:22:49.451Z"
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v": 331,
    "shares": [
        {
            "sh_Id": {
                "$oid": "596b2d65d65e092778a41e31"
            },
            "Date": {
                "$date": "2017-07-16T09:09:57.666Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "sh_Id": {
                "$oid": "596b2d9e371b5c2194775c0d"
            },
            "Date": {
                "$date": "2017-07-16T09:10:54.701Z"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Desired Result:**

```
       [ {
            "p_Id": {
                "$oid": "596b16b1c657d21d8048287d"
            },
            "Date": {
                "$date": "2017-07-16T07:33:06.238Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "sh_Id": {
                "$oid": "596b2d65d65e092778a41e31"
            },
            "Date": {
                "$date": "2017-07-16T09:09:57.666Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "sh_Id": {
                "$oid": "596b2d9e371b5c2194775c0d"
            },
            "Date": {
                "$date": "2017-07-16T09:10:54.701Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "p_Id": {
                "$oid": "596b3068183c4f24d853f228"
            },
            "Date": {
                "$date": "2017-07-16T09:22:49.451Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "p_Id": {
                "$oid": "596b3071183c4f24d853f229"
            },
            "Date": {
                "$date": "2017-07-16T09:22:57.911Z"
            }
        }]
```

**My Query:**

```
    Activity.aggregate([
         { $match : { user : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(data.user) } },
         { $unwind: "$posts" }, { $unwind: "$shares"},
         { $project : { _id: 0, posts: 1, shares: 1 } }
         ]).exec(function(err,result){
                console.log(result);
         });
```

But this query gives results in pairs. i.e. in subdocument the same post occurs for each share.for e.g.

**My Result:**

```
[ { posts:
     { p_Id: 596b16b1c657d21d8048287d,
       Date: 2017-07-16T07:33:06.214Z },
    shares:
     { sh_Id: 596b2d65d65e092778a41e31,
       Date: 2017-07-16T09:09:57.666Z } },
  { posts:
     { p_Id: 596b16b1c657d21d8048287d,
       Date: 2017-07-16T07:33:06.214Z },
    shares:
     { sh_Id: 596b2d9e371b5c2194775c0d,
       Date: 2017-07-16T09:10:54.701Z } },
  { posts:
     { p_Id: 596b16b1c657d21d8048287d,
       Date: 2017-07-16T07:33:06.214Z },
    shares:
     { sh_Id: 596b30c1183c4f24d853f22c,
       Date: 2017-07-16T09:24:17.621Z } }]
```

Comment: It's called [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/). It makes the 2 arrays 1. So you can then `$unwind` without a cartesian product of the other array entries.

Comment: I am unable to understand. I have used unwind 2 times but how will i get a unique unwind for each posts and shares. Will you please elaborate or kindly post a piece of code for the same

Comment: You should understand better if you actually looked at the linked documentation page. Use `{ "$project": { "combined": { "$concatArrays": [ "$posts", "$shares" ] } } },{ "$unwind": "$combined" }`. It makes "one" array for you to `$unwind`.

Comment: Thanks!! .. It worked and I got it too